# Express - Accessing top-level express function through dot-notation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In a simple javascript file, we can use express by adding these two lines of code at the beginning (after installing it through npm):

```
var foo = require('express');
var app = foo();
```

Now, according to the express API guide:

> The app object conventionally denotes the Express application. Create it by calling the top-level express() function exported by the Express module

Since the app object is calling the top-level express() function, how come am I not able to just simply use:

```
var app = foo.express();
```

Comment: "app object is calling the top-level express" That is incorrect. You are calling the module exported by express and assigning the outcome to `app`. This has to do with the CommonJS module system, and is not specific to Express.

Comment: @E_net4 If var app is calling the module exported by express then what does var express do?

Comment: `express` is a function which you call to instantiate application object.

Comment: Please update your question. Do you understand how `require` works?

Comment: @E_net4 I believe I understand it. It simply retrieves the called module and puts it in the cache. My question has to do with the syntax. Why are we not able to directly call the express function through dot notation.

Comment: Actually, you would write it as `require("express")()`, unless the same function is exported as a property with that name.

Comment: I am sorry guys, I think I've messed up some stuff. I just remembered reading in a book not long ago that we can access functions directly from other files by using require and the dot notation.

Comment: @E_net4 please read my answer to this question, I think I have cleared my misconception and please consider removing the downvote.

Comment: @dfsq please read my answer to this question, I think I have cleared my misconception and please consider removing the downvote.

Comment: It is inappropriate to assume that one downvoted a question without mentioning so. Moreover, answers are evaluated separately, and do not improve the question's quality. In particular, you should ask yourself "who will benefit from this question in the future", and rephrase it to better address your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The require function that was passed 'express' returns module.exports, which holds the top level function express(), something similar to:

```
module.exports = express(){...}
```

That is why we still need to call it either through:

```
var foo = require('express');
var app = foo();
```

or

```
var app = require('express')();
```

You cannot use:

```
var foo = require('express');
var app = foo.express();
```

because it was not set up that way, you could use it if the express module looked something like this:

```
module.exports.express = express(){...}
```

I don't know the reason as to why you would choose one over the other, I only know that the second technique simply exposes your function directly.

Answer (score 0):

The first line assigns whatever the module 'express' exports to a variable named `express`. Different modules will export different things (objects, functions). Express exports a function.

The line:

```
var app = express()
```

executes the function. This function generates the express application object. This object has all the methods that you use to handle requests in your standard express apps.